# Shiny - uiOutput and UI layout problems

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, reactive-programming

[image: Why do I get "col-sm-4"?]

Right now, I'm encapsulating the UI on the right side as a variable, and I want the UI on the right to change based on the "Module Selected." Here's what I'm doing right now to do this:

```
ui <- navbarPage('test',
  tabPanel('Analysis',
    fluidRow(
      ui_core,
      uiOutput('ui_module')
    ) 
  )
)

output$ui_module <- renderUI({
# observeEvent(input$core_module_selection, {
  current_module <- NULL
  if(!is.null(input$core_module_selection) && input$core_module_selection != 'Core') {
    current_module <- rval$module_ui[[match(input$core_module_selection, rval$module_names)]]
    rval$ui_module <<- current_module
  }

  return(rval$ui_module)
})
```

I'm using reactive values (rval) for the `ui_module` variable, which holds the UI I want to render:

```
ui_filetrans <-
tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel('File Transfer',
    p("filetrans")
  )
)
register_module("File Transfer", ui_filetrans)
```

which should end up like this:

```
ui <- navbarPage('Granatum',
  tabPanel('Analysis',
    fluidRow(
      ui_core,
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel('File Transfer',
          p("filetrans")
        )
      )
    ) 
  )
)
```

But, instead, I get this weird text (I'd guess it's a Bootstrap class or something) that supposedly comes from the tag... and not the full object.

What am I doing wrong? Is the object's type being changed once I assign it to a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turns out that by passing Shiny UI elements to a vector, you will implicitly remove some of the information of the object.**

**The solution is to use lists, and use double square brackets to index:**

```
rval$module_ui <- list(ui_core)

rval$module_ui <- c(rval$module_ui, list(module))
```

`c()`, the concatenate function, works very much the same for lists, but ensure that you turn "atoms" or atomic components into a list before concatenation.

Comment: I think `shiny::tagList` is meant to be used specifically for lists of tags, maybe use that